Young bullied teen finds portal to alternate reality, fighting in the clouds
My memories of this movie are sporadic.
I know it's kids/family. It's martial arts/maybe manga based tho live action. High flying, cloud bouncing cheesy graphics. Its Oriental/Asian production style tho the main character might be Caucasian.
There's a young teen who gets bullied. Finds a portal to an alternate reality and ultimately saves the day. Or something like that.
I see an orb or box he finds. Either after a fire in a shop or given to him by a friendly or family person.  I see a rooftop scene that might be where the portal is. I see martial arts style fighting in the clouds. There's a dark castle where much of the movie takes place  (I think). Def a lot of fighting and a major battle inside the castle. 

Could be The Forbidden Kingdom

A discovery made by a kung fu obsessed American teen sends him on an adventure to China, where he joins up with a band of martial arts warriors in order to free the imprisoned Monkey King.





Based on the question that is exactly what I was thinking
